# Замена текстовых смайлов на графические

Tags: javascript, замена

Доброго времени суток.

Подскажите, пожалуйста. Я новичок в js.
Вот обращаюсь за помощью к знающим людям.

Нужно преобразовать текстовые смайлы на графические.

**JS:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function insertSmile(smile)
{
document.chatform.smile.value += smile;
}        
</script
```

**Смайл, на который пользователь тыкает:**

```
<img src="smiles/smile.gif" alt=":)" onclick="insertSmile(' :) ')" />
```

**TEXTAREA:**

```
<form method="POST" name="chatform">
<textarea  name="smile"></textarea>
</form>
```

*****Буду очень благодарен.*****

**Обновление**

Сам сделал следующее: добавил графическую картинку смайлика. Пользователь видит эту картинку около textarea, жмёт на смайлик, он вносится в textarea. При нажатии на кнопку "отправить" смайлик переносится в область с сообщениями, но в текстовом варианте, а нужно, чтобы он переносился в графическом.

Comment: @Nikita Shpak, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 2):

В `textarea` нельзя хранить какие-либо `DOM` элементы, это можно делать в блоке с атрибутом **`contenteditable="true"`**.

Comment: @Ni55aN
извините, может, я неправильно сформулировал. В textarea не нужно. Нужно, чтобы он из textarea переносился в область с комментариями в графическом стиле.

Answer (score 1):

Сообщения наверняка хранятся где-то, так? В текстовых файлах или в БД - не важно, и не важно, чем их оттуда выдирают. Важно, что перед тем как сообщение в виде текста попадёт на страницу (сформируется конечная HTML страница с сообщениями), все смайлы (коды смайлов ":-)", ":D", ":-D", "o_O") заменятся на `<img src="smiles/smile.gif" alt=":)">` (используя в PHP функцию [subst_replace](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.substr-replace.php), например)  и аналогичные, таким образом на странице со списком сообщений вместо кодов со смайлами будут теги с картинками смайлов.

**UPD:**
Лично у меня на Javascript вышло так:

```
<html>
<head>

</head>
<body>

<div name="message">Тестовое сообщение :)</div>
<div name="message">Тестовое сообщение :-)</div>
<div name="message">Тестовое сообщение :D</div>
<div name="message">Тестовое сообщение :(</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
var elems = document.getElementsByName("message");
var smiles = [":)",":D",":-)",":("];
for(var i=0; i<elems.length; i++) 
{
    for (var x=0;x<smiles.length;x++)
    {
    if (elems[i].innerHTML.indexOf(smiles[x])>-1)
        {
            elems[i].innerHTML = elems[i].innerHTML.replace(smiles[x],"<img title=\""+smiles[x]+"\" src=\"smile.gif\">");
        }
    }

}

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: либо извращаться и Java-Script'ом все вхождения с кодом смайлов на странице заменять на картинки смайлов но это изврат...

Comment: @cyberdream
вот я пробовал вот так, но ведь это бред:

var temp = "";
temp = temp.replace(/:)>/g, "smiles/smile.gif");

Comment: @cyberdream
подскажите, как извратить. )  
У меня там от силы 4-5 смайлов всего.

Comment: Короче, решил я проблему. В любом случае, спасибо всем, кто откликнулся.

Comment: Какое решение-то? А то я тут извращался с этой Javascript около часа, а оказалось, что ответ есть. Поделитесь. :)

Comment: @cyberdream
извините, не подумал о Вас)
Вот тут решение нашёл:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3055515/replace-a-list-of-emoticons-with-their-images

Comment: @Nikita Shpak вообще если нашли ответ сами, то запостите его в качестве ответа на свой вопрос, и тогда можно вопрос закрывать. :) А так получается, что вопрос решен, а ответа нет, и он висит открытый.